# Write bytes to End Of File PNG format

Tags: c#, .net

I have a resource file contain a PNG file I want to write byte array to the `End Of File` PNG image but when saving the file from stream remove byte array, I want to write hidden bytes to PNG file, How to resolve this issue?

```
        public void Method()
        {
            using (var reader = new ResourceReader("My.resource"))
            {
                var iter = reader.GetEnumerator();
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var writer = new System.Resources.ResourceWriter(ms);
                while (iter.MoveNext())
                {
                    var key = iter.Key as string;
                    var value = iter.Value as Bitmap;
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    value.Save(stream, value.RawFormat);
                    byte[] b = new byte[] {0x11, 0x22, 0x33};
                    stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                    Image bitmap = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    writer.AddResource(key, bitmap);
                }
                writer.Generate();
                File.WriteAllBytes("My1.resource", ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What issue?  You described what you want, but not what the problem is.

Comment: Saved resource files are not written bytes to eof PNG. `byte[] b = new byte[] {0x11, 0x22, 0x33};`

Comment: You should check the remarks section here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx